# Combine date and time with a 'T'

Tags: php, date

In my PHP application needs to combine date a time with character 'T',

I needs the output like `2015-04-20T01:30:00` (combine with T)

My PHP code as follows

```
$durationFrom =  date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$durationFrom);
```

Comment: `date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s',$durationFrom);` Where is the problem?! It's called escaping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put it right into your date definition:

```
$durationFrom =  date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s',$durationFrom);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with -

```
$durationFrom =  date('Y-m-d',$durationFrom).'T'.date('H:i:s',$durationFrom);
```

Answer (score 1):

So you need the ISO 8601 notation?

```
$durationFrom : date('c', $durationFrom);
```

Comment: *So you need the ISO 8601 notation?* Don't use answers to ask OP questions! Use comments for clarification!

Comment: This is the answer. If you want a T between date and time, that is the ISO standard.

Comment: 1. Then don't write your answer as a question 2. ... and if OP also would have wanted +00:00 at the end!